# TeXstudio installation problem on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS using PPA

Tags: apt, software-installation, ppa

I'm experiencing an issue with installation of TeXstudio. The installation is being performed using the PPA on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. Provided error and apt-cache policy.

Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
Unpacking texstudio (2.12.16-0~201905181623~ubuntu18.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/texstudio_2.12.16-0~201905181623~ubuntu18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/texstudio/tabletemplate_fullyframed_firstBold.js', which is also in package texstudio-doc 2.12.6+debian-2
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/texstudio_2.12.16-0~201905181623~ubuntu18.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
computer:~$ apt-cache policy texstudio texstudio-doc
texstudio:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.12.16-0~201905181623~ubuntu18.04.1
  Version table:
     2.12.16-0~201905181623~ubuntu18.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/sunderme/texstudio/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     2.12.6+debian-2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
texstudio-doc:
  Installed: 2.12.6+debian-2
  Candidate: 2.12.6+debian-2
  Version table:
 *** 2.12.6+debian-2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

After removing the PPA, was able to install. Although not using the PPA is a temporary solution, would like resolution to the problem and to install the more current version under the PPA.

Comment: Try to remove `texstudio-doc` first and then install from the ppa.

Comment: Hi Harris. Your solution worked. I removed `texstudio-doc`, added the PPA, performed `sudo apt update` followed by the `sudo apt install texstudio`. Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to run

```
sudo apt remove texstudio-doc
```

that fixes the issue.